# bundle install fail "..does not appear to be a git repository fatal: Could not read from remote repository."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I have a gem file in which i am trying to get 
"gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', git: 'https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git'"

Using `bundle install` command and it gives the below error:

```
C:\Sooraj\Playdrone\playdrone-master>bundle install

Fetching https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git
fatal: '/cygdrive/c/Sooraj/Playdrone/playdrone-master/C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.
2.0/cache/bundler/git/twitter-bootstrap-rails-eff46a5fc3c9c652c290119047c5ec9247068903' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
Retrying git clone --no-checkout --quiet "C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/cache/bundler/git/twitter-bootstrap-rails-eff46a5fc3c9c652c290119047c5ec9247068903" "C:/
Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-38476dbd7f9a" 
due to error (2/4): 
Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: 
command `git clone --no-checkout --quiet "C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/cache/bundler/git/twitter-bootstrap-rails-eff46a5fc3c9c652c290119047c5ec9247068903" "C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/bundler/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-38476dbd7f9a"` 
in directory C:/Sooraj/Playdrone/playdrone-master has failed.
If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory 
'C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/cache/bundler/git/twitter-bootstrap-rails-eff46a5fc3c9c652c290119047c5ec9247068903'
fatal: '/cygdrive/c/Sooraj/Playdrone/playdrone-master/C:/Ruby22/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/cache/bundler/git/twitter-bootstrap-rails-eff46a5fc3c9c652c290119047c5ec9247068903' 
does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

But the git url is correct.
Its asking me to delete the cache folder and I delete it and run the command and I get the same error.

Can anyone please help what this error is and how I can rectify?

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to [bundler/issues/2571](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/2571), where Cygwin was installed first (before running `bundle install` from a `CMD.exe` session, outside Cygwin)

> Figured it out.
>   The `bundler` installation that came with `RailsInstaller` has its own git installation, but when I was calling it from cygwin it was using cygwin's git and didn't know how to handle windows-style path names.
>   When I tested it under `CMD`, I had run it from cygwin so that PATH was set wrong. 
>   I renamed cygwin's git to "`git_old`".

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails), it should be:

```
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git'
```

You should replace 'https' with 'git'.

Why are you pulling the latest build?  This is generally not a good idea unless you have a reason to do so as it is not likely to be as stable as a release.  Generally, you will want the latest stable release.

Comment: yes sir i tried that as well and it says
the same error for ...and the thing is i downloaded a project from git hub...they have this gemfile along with gemfile.lock so should i delete their gemfile.lock and then run bundle install ?? because that lock file is theirs..

Comment: Yes you should definitely run bundle install yourself.  Gemfile.lock is specific to your project (your combination of gems/versions).  I guess I must have gotten something wrong in my answer hence the unexplained downvote, but I would still strongly recommend that you just use the latest release of the gem if possible by putting `gem twitter-bootstrap-rails` in your gemfile and running bundle install.

Comment: yeah sir thats rectified i am stuck with the below issue for 4 hours
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31236420/rugged-gem-installation-issue-possibly-with-lingit2-on-windows....i installed cmake and now stuck with "checking for cmake... yes
checking for gmake... no
checking for make... yes
checking for pkg-config... no
ERROR: pkg-config is required to build Rugged.
*** extconf.rb failed ***"

Comment: can i install rugged gem in windows easily? i seems to have lot of inherent dependencies

Comment: Sorry @Srini I am not that familiar with development in a Windows environment.  Did you try just installing the latest release of the gem?  If so, maybe update your OP with your current gem file and error you are seeing.