# Rugged gem installation issue possibly with libgit2 on Windows

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems

I am using Windows and my `Gemfile` has this line:

```
gem 'rugged'
```

When I run `bundle install` it's giving me this error:

```
Installing rugged 0.21.0 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby21/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb --use-system-libraries
    checking for cmake... no 
    ERROR: CMake is required to build Rugged.

*** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.

Check the mkmf.log file for more details. You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby21/bin/ruby

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rugged-0.21.0 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.1.0/rugged-0.21.0/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing rugged(0.21.0), and Bundler cannot continue.

Make sure that `gem install rugged -v '0.21.0'` succeeds before
bundling.
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with `libgit2` but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually a question I'm surprised isn't asked more. But `rugged` requires `CMake` & `pkg-config` in order to compile correctly.

Just because we can, we will extract them into the *DevKit* itself.

**First** let's grab a copy of each:

`CMake` is fairly straight forward, [here's the download link](http://www.cmake.org/files/v3.2/cmake-3.2.3-win32-x86.zip).
`pkg-config` is a little bit more complicated, it has some dependencies and such. However, there's a [nice package bundled with the dependencies](http://iweb.dl.sourceforge.net/project/mingw-w64/Toolchains%20targetting%20Win64/Personal%20Builds/ray_linn/64bit-libraries/pkg-config/pkg-config-0.26.7z).

Then **Extract** the proper files into the *DevKit*

Once you have them you need to open up each archive([requires 7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/)) and open the *top level* folder in the archive.
From there you need extract the `bin` and `share` directories from the archive into the *DevKit* root directory.
*It should just merge the directories into the existing ones and nothing should be overwritten or deleted.*

Try installing again and it should **just work** and you don't dirty your  `PATH` with more stuff.

Comment: thanks dude....now there is a new area where i stuck..it has to do with libv8 and rubyracer on  windows pc.

Comment: That one should be answered here somewhere, if not ask another question.

Comment: thanks dude....now there is a new area where i stuck..it has to do with libv8 and rubyracer on  windows pc.
A lot has been said Like
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19673714/rails-gem-install-error-error-installing-libv8-error-failed-to-build-gem-nati
and so on.
But they seem to be not working.
I tried running 
C:\Sooraj\Playdrone\playdrone-master>gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.3' -- --with-system-v8 first and then when i do bundle install below error is coming
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254645/libv8-and-rubyracer-error-after-using-gem-install-libv8-v-3-16-14-3-with