# Installing "libv8" gem for "therubyracer" on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, rubygems

I'm having trouble installing `therubyracer` gem on Windows.

Using `Ruby 2.1.6 32-bit` and running

```
gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.3' -- --with-system-v8
```

This is the error I get:

```
Installing therubyracer 0.12.1 with native extensions

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby21/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lpthread... no
checking for v8.h... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby21/bin/ruby
        --with-pthreadlib
        --without-pthreadlib
        --enable-debug
        --disable-debug
        --with-v8-dir
        --without-v8-dir
        --with-v8-include
        --without-v8-include=${v8-dir}/include
        --with-v8-lib
        --without-v8-lib=${v8-dir}/lib
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/location.rb:50:in 
`configure': You have chosen to use the version of V8 found on your system (Libv8::Location::System::NotFoundError)
and *not* the one that is bundle with the libv8 rubygem. However,
it could not be located. please make sure you have a version of
v8 that is compatible with 3.16.14.3 installed. You may
need to special --with-v8-dir options if it is in a non-standard
location

thanks,
The Mgmt

        from C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/lib/libv8.rb:7:in `configure_makefile'
        from extconf.rb:32:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/therubyracer-0.12.1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.1.0/therubyracer-0.12.1/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing therubyracer (0.12.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install therubyracer -v '0.12.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [therubyracer gem on windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6356450/therubyracer-gem-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

This is kinda a double edged sword, the `libv8` gem itself tries to build `v8` and things get crazy because it's using `*nix` programs to test and setup the environment.

So to fix it you have to use `-- --with-system-v8` so it doesn't try to build `v8`. Unfortunately that advice already presumes you have a copy of `v8` somewhere on your system. Which you don't, obviously.

The quick and easy is to install [node.js](https://nodejs.org/) and make sure it gets added to your path, since it is statically compiled the library is in `node.exe`. *There may be some weird errors with that approach, BUT I don't think you will run into any of them.*

Of course, in reality you shouldn't need `therubyracer` or `libv8` because Windows ships with `JScript` which is a JavaScript engine itself, or if nothing else `node` will also suffice.

Comment: so are you suggesting the below steps
1)install node.js
2)run gem install libv8
3)then run gem intall rubyracer
just  wanna confirm..thanks

Comment: My first suggestion would be to remove it from the `Gemfile` if it's there. If it's another gem's dependency then yes.

Comment: well i commented rubyracer and installed bundle successfuly but when i run rails c its asking 

C:\Sooraj\Playdrone\playdrone-master>rails c
[WARNING] Please install gem 'therubyracer' to use Less.
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/less-2.5.1/lib/less/java_script/v8_context.rb
:2:in `require': cannot load such file -- v8 (LoadError)..

i know its been asked before but there is not solid solution can you please help..thanks a lot

Comment: Did you try installing nodejs and retrying with `node.exe` in your path?

Comment: yes..the thing is Less is dependent on rubyracer and i cannot install rubyracer..it seems to be a common problem among users

Comment: so the above error is coming no matter what i do :-(

Answer (score 0):

> Solution from [Charles Lowell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6359265/5157221):

No, there is no way that I know of to currently install this gem on windows. The problem is that there is currently no pre-compiled version of the `libv8` gem for Windows, and the source version is only compatible with *nix. It does not necessarily have to be that way, it just requires somebody taking the time to make the compile work for Windows. https://github.com/fractaloop/libv8

That said, Windows should come with a JScript, the Microsoft JavaScript runtime, which rails (via [execjs](https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs)) will automatically detect and use, so you should be able to just remove your dependency on `therubyracer`.